# Adding Event Handler to Third Party JS - Bad practice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Someone asked me to help them append a function to a page that utilized JQuery UI Tabs. They wanted this function so that when a tab was highlighted and you clicked on it again it would bring you to an external page with more information.

I wrote the following function which, when a tab was clicked would fire. It would add a second event handler to the selected tab. When that second event fired it would remove itself, and then be added again by the first click event. This would prevent duplication.

```
 function activeClick(id) {
//add event for active tab
$('.ui-state-active #' + id).on("click.activeclick", function() { 

//determine what tab was selected and clicked by pulling the text value of 
//the tab into a variable

var tabLocation = $('.ui-state-active #' + id).text(); 
//Open new window and show the correct department page
window.open("http://www.website.com/dept/" + tabLocation); 

//remove the click event referenced by the activeclick namespace preventing duplications.
$('.ui-state-active #' + id).off("click.activeclick"); 
});
}
```

I had to send it through our third-party IT department for approval and they have given it the 'okay' although they told me it was bad practice to append an event handler to an already existing event. I don't quite see why that would be or how else besides editing the UI Tabs file(which I think is an over reaction to this request), I would be able to add this event handler.

I feel like they may just be saying it's bad practice because they were the first people asked to do this and they had come back and said that it was an impossible request. So, in effect, I unknowingly showed them up and they might just be saving face. But, on the off chance I thought I would ask, are they right? Is this bad practice?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with adding a second event handler to a given event.  You can have as many listeners to any event as you want and the system is purposely designed to work that way so that different pieces of code can listen to the same event without having to coordinate.

Comment: It's not bad practice, but it's bad design. It's not entirely your fault either. The reason why it'd be bad design is because of maintainability and overhead. If anything happens or changes to the existing event, the event handler that depends on that could break.. so there must be a note that explains that something is depending on it. This is one of the reason why devs are moving away from directly manipulating the dom using jquery and switching to js frameworks like angular or ember

Comment: @sksallaj I agree with you on the design. My overall goal was to touch as little as possible and I explained to the person who requested this that some changes to the tabs may cause a break to this specific piece of code if not done correctly, though it would not be difficult to fix. I was told that the tabs should remain virtually static on the page for as long as it is utilized and nothing that the code depends on will be adjusted.(at least without asking me about it) - so I feel fairly confident that it should age well enough.

Comment: IMHO, your question is missing some context. It must have a good reson why your IT departement think it is a bad practice/workaround. BTW, instead of unbind event, use a specific toggling data, e.g something like `$(this).data('toggleClick', !$(this).data('toggleClick'))` and check for it in click handler. And the reson you are unbinding click as you explained in your comment, referring to my previous one (now both removed) means **you are nesting handlers which is bad for sure.**

Comment: ↑↑↑ I'm more thinking your IT team is referring to that and i guess, instead, you would have better to delegate event. And as a side note, as IDs must be unique on document context, use ID selector directly.

Comment: If you want more opinions, you should share minimalistic sample where your code logic would fix an issue without any better workaround.

Comment: @A.Wolff haha, yeah I wish those comments were still there. I posted my response and yours was gone so I removed mine. Unfortunately no, there isn't really any other context. I told you all the information that I know. I'm confused why toggling/checking data would be a better solution?  The event's added when the tab is active, removed if it's clicked again.Is that inefficient comparitively? And the reason why I point to the ui-state-active and the id is because when you remove that class from the id the handler is removed automatically. It's cleaner because I don't have to unbind it manually.

Comment: @zfrisch `And the reason why I point to the ui-state-active and the id is because when you remove that class from the id the handler is removed automatically` I'm really not sure to understand what that means, sorry. `Is that inefficient comparitively?` It is really ineficient compare to checking for any switchable data inside handler, ya. Even it doesn't really matter in most cases

Comment: @A.Wolff Yeah, I actually made a mistake in my logic on that one. You're right. Good call. I'll have to look this over. Thanks for the discussion. I'll try to put up a fiddle later on today to see if I can improve what's already written.